# Update domain emailid

Tags: oracle

I want to get specific part from the emailid as like below example:

```
Example abc.xyz@xxxxx.com
```

I want email id portion start **strong text** ing with @ as like below

```
@xxxxx.com
```

I tried to do the same with the SURSTR() function in oracle.
I just want to identify the emailid like

```
@xxxxx.com
```

and want to update it like

```
@yyyyy.com using oracle.
```

Can any one help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
update your_table
set email_add = substr(email_add, 0, instr(email_add, '@')) || 'yyyy.com'
```

For example, using dual:

```
select substr('abc@yahoo.com', 0, instr('abc@yahoo.com', '@')) || 'gmail.com' from dual
```

gives abc@gmail.com

Comment: Thank u so much for your quick response.

Comment: This exactly which I want